# WPF delete datagrid row based on cell value

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am facing a problem right now, I need to delete a `datagrid` row based on **1** cell value, code samples below:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid
    x:Name="AccountGrid"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    GridLinesVisibility="Vertical" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    CanUserAddRows="False"
    CanUserReorderColumns="False"
    CanUserResizeColumns="False"
    CanUserSortColumns="False" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CanUserResizeRows="False" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
    Margin="208,0,0,135"
>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="VM-Name" Binding="{Binding Path=vmName}" MinWidth="80" IsReadOnly="True" />
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Profile" Binding="{Binding Path=profileN}" MinWidth="100" IsReadOnly="True" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

How I add items:

```
public class AddToGrid
{
   public string vmName   { get; set; }
   public string profileN { get; set; }
}

this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
   var dat = new AddToGrid { vmName = clientSockets.Find(item => item.Item1 == current).Item2, profileN = profile.Item1 };
   AccountGrid.Items.Add( dat );
});
```

What I need to do is **Delete** a row from the `grid`, using the `VM-Name`, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't. Bind the grid's ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection. Then add items to the ObservableCollection and delete items from the ObservableCollection. That method is extremely easy and foolproof. Your method is neither. What is `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` doing? What is your DataContext?

Comment: Well i posted all the code that is related to the data grid on the post, so there's really not much too it, if you could provide me an example i could reference from that'd be great

Comment: So you have no DataContext and `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` is just decoration? It shouldn't be hard to find hundreds of examples of using ItemsSource with ObservableCollection here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Rename your `AddToGrid` class to `MyGridRow` and move it to be a public type instead of a nested type.
2. Add `using System.Linq;` and `using System.Collections.ObjectModel;` to your C# code-behind file.
3. In your XAML code-behind, add this public property:

   ```
   public ObservableCollection<MyGridRow> MyGridRows { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MyGridRow>();
   ```
4. Change your XAML to this:

   ```
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyGridRows}" ...>

   </DataGrid>
   ```
5. Change your code that adds items to this:

   ```
   String vmName = clientSockets.Find( item => item.Item1 == current ).Item2;
   String profile = profileN = profile.Item1;
   this.MyGridRows.Add( new MyGridRow { VMName = vmName, ProfileN = profile } );
   ```
6. To remove a row, do this:

   ```
   MyGridRow itemToRemove = this.MyGridRows
       .FirstOrDefault( pair => pair.Item.VMName == "someName" )

   if( itemToRemove != null )
   {
       this.MyGridRows.Remove( itemToRemove );
   }
   ```

Comment: Easier would be to: `var element = this.MyGridRows
    .Select( (item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index } )
    .FirstOrDefault( pair => pair.Item.vmName == "someName" ) ;
     if(element != null) MyGridRows.Remove(element)`.

And he need to set DataContext too :d

Comment: Thanks for that! although it says MyGridRows does not contain a definition of Select.

Comment: @TricksterJoe Add `using System.Linq;` to your C# files.

Comment: Hey, when it comes to editing a cell,
`MyGridRows.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index })
    .FirstOrDefault(pair => pair.Item.vmName == hostName).Item.vmName ="Offline - " + hostName;`
i need to do myGrid.Items.Refresh(); for the row to get updated , is it valid?

Comment: @TricksterJoe If you add `INotifyPropertyChanged` to your `MyGridRow` class then you won't need to call `Refresh`.

Comment: Thanks, was simple enough!